# How to make Rotate Dial with rivet?

Tags: game-design, custom-game-pieces

First off I'm not sure what a Rotate Dial is actually called. I am thinking of something similar to a HeroClix base (a rotating top piece with a hole, which reveals different stats on the bottom piece as it rotates), but I'm trying to make them out of cardboard. So a 2 circle pieces of chipboard, one with a notch cut out, and somehow attached.

I was thinking I can attach them together with a plastic (or metal) rivet. However since my pieces are smallish ~1.5in, I'm having a hard time finding a small enough rivet.

Is there a name for this?

Is there a known good way to make this thing?

Comment: Thebes has a similar component, if I understand right, and the rules just call it a wheel. http://boardgamegeek.com/image/2334221/thebes Not a very helpful name for searching for more like it, unfortunately.

Comment: That makes it difficult to google... :(

Comment: And yes that is exactly what I'm talking about. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah, hopefully there's another common name out there. (The Thebes example isn't much help for you, since it's several inches across.)

Comment: Find some FFG X-Wing miniatures on eBay and wash the dials with acetone?

Comment: That is a pretty expensive way to go. If I just needed a few that might be a good options, but I need about a hundred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "wheel" and "dial" (or "game dial") are other names for this.

I found a couple BGG threads with some suggestions:

[How do you make a game dial?](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/802826/how-do-you-make-game-dial)
[Plastic grommets for cardboard wheels (ala BSG)](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1188836/plastic-grommets-cardboard-wheels-ala-bsg)

The main things you could search for are:

- (paper) binding screws/screw posts/chicago screws (there's a site called Chicago Screws that sells them, but it's also a generic name)
- paper rivets
- brads/brass fasteners

I know you said it you couldn't find small enough rivets, but I searched a bit and it looks like paper rivets are made down to a few mm across,

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://www.garrettwade.com/document-fastener/p/25S07.02/ or this https://www.chicagoscrews.com/Small-Head-Unslotted-Plastic-Chicago-Screws ?

Comment: @ohmusama The former looks like a type of paper rivets that might not be what you want, and the latter looks like binding screws/screw posts/chicago screws. I don't think any of the names refer to something where every single thing with that name will work (they could all be too wide or long, the rivets could be too tight, etc), but they should all include something that would, so they're all things you can search for or ask for in stores.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how sturdy these need to be you could try attaching the pieces together with a [brass brad](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/613827/Office-Depot-Brand-Round-Head-Fasteners/?cm_mmc=PLA-_-Google-_-Basic_Supplies-_-613827-VQ6-42102187916-VQ16c-VQ17-pla-VQ18-online-VQ19-613827-VQ20-75211488596-VQ21-).  Granted it will not work for terribly long before it gets worn out, but if it's just for prototyping it should be sufficient.